# Duda con Pyserial en Mac

Tags: python, arduino, utf-8

Mi problema es el siguiente, acabo de adquirir un equipo MacBook Pro, anteriormente usaba Windows 10 para hacer practicas en Python conectandolo a Arduino mediante el `Pyserial` el cual lo incluía el programa `Pycharm`. Ahora que estoy suando Mac el programa `Pycharm` no me reconoce el puerto que me identifica arduino, en este caso es:

**"/dev/cu.usbmodem1421"**

Al momento de compilar, me da el siguiente error:

```
"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file 
/Users/StoomBassCow/PycharmProjects/untitled1/aperro/holamundo.py on line 4,
but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details"
```

¿Alguien que me pueda explicar cual es el problema?

Mi código es:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

print sys.getdefaultencoding()

import serial

puertoserie = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421',9600)

while True:
    tecla = input("Presiona la tecla 1 para encender el led")

    if tecla.lower() == 'e':    
        puertoserie.write(b'e')
    else:
        puertoserie.write(b'a')
```

Comment: Que versión de python estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estás usando la cabecera `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` y no veo ningún caracter extraño solo me puedo imaginar que la falla se debe a algún espacio en otra codificación. Así que prueba eliminando todos los espacios, en especial las de la linea que menciona en el error, también vuelve a identarlo pero usando exclusivamente espacios en blanco en lugar de tabs.